# How to add two configurations in the showTimePicker build?

Tags: flutter, dart, datetimepicker, showtimepicker

I am setting up a showTimePicker and I need to set the theme and time format for it. Both are configured in the widget builder but I do not know how to place both configurations to be returned.

This is the code of the TimePicker configuration, I leave commented the lines of the second configuration that I need to add.

```
final TimeOfDay selectedTime = await showTimePicker(
  context: context,
  initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
    return (
      MediaQuery(
        data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: true),
        child: child,
    ));
      /*Theme(
        data: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
            primary: redColor,
            onPrimary: Colors.white,
            surface: greyColor,
            onSurface: greyVeryLightColor,
          ),
          dialogBackgroundColor: greyLightColor,
        ),
        child: child,
      )*/
  },
);
```

Both work separately, but I don't know how to merge the settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply wrap the child of MediaQuery widget with Theme widget. Please see the code below :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title:const Text("Flutter Demo")),
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return RaisedButton(
        onPressed: () async {
          final TimeOfDay selectedTime = await showTimePicker(
            context: context,
            initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
              return MediaQuery(
                data: MediaQuery.of(context)
                    .copyWith(alwaysUse24HourFormat: true),
                child: Theme(
                    data: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
                      colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
                        primary: Colors.red,
                        onPrimary: Colors.white,
                        surface: Colors.grey,
                        onSurface: Colors.grey[100],
                      ),
                      dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.grey[400],
                    ),
                    child: child),
              );
            },
          );
          print(selectedTime);
        },
        child: const Text("Show Time Picker"));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I searched how to do it but can't find it.